# JavaScript get the value of input in a div

Tags: javascript

I want to get the value of an input in a div. 
I've tried `document.getElementById('id').getElementsByTagName('input')` but somehow I can't get the value.

HTML:

```
<div id="ST_RTM1_352X-MESSAGE_TYPED01_TXT">
    <input class="MobileEditDisabled ABLED" value="E" size="2" maxlength="2" type="text">
</div>
```

JS :

```
var getV = document.getElementById("ST_RTM1_352X-MESSAGE_TYPED01_TXT").getElementsByTagName('input');
alert(getV.value);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/2aLn33hn/

Comment: getElement ***s*** ByTagName. ElementSSSSSS. Plural.

Answer (score 2):

Or be more clever:

```
var getV = document.querySelector("#ST_RTM1_352X-MESSAGE_TYPED01_TXT input");
alert(getV.value);
```

Comment: Useful answer (aside from the snide intro)

Answer (score 1):

`getV` contains a collection of nodes. You need to get first element `getV[0]` or `getV.item(0)` and then do another operations.

Answer (score 1):

`.getElementsByTagName` returns a collection - reference the index you want:

```
var getV = document.getElementById("ST_RTM1_352X-MESSAGE_TYPED01_TXT").getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot de position because getV will get a collention's nodes, use `[0]` to get the node:

```
var getV = document.getElementById("ST_RTM1_352X-MESSAGE_TYPED01_TXT").getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

[DEMO LIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/wilfredo1285/2aLn33hn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `[0]` after `getElementsByTagName('input')`.

Answer (score 1):

[A Solution...](http://jsfiddle.net/2aLn33hn/2/)

Lets say it like this:
My Version takes the Div Element and searches for All Input child Elements.
It works ;)

```
var getV = document.getElementById("ST_RTM1_352X-
MESSAGE_TYPED01_TXT").getElementsByTagName('input');
alert("Inputelements in the Div:" +getV.length);
for (var i = 0; i<getV.length; i++){
    alert("Value of input " + i + ": " + getV[i].value);   
}
```